Predicting the Next Event's Timestamp Based on Historical Data with Possible Patterns?
I'm working on a personal project where I aim to predict the time of the next event based on a series of historical timestamps. The dataset I have consists of around 400k timestamps of past events.
While analyzing the data, I've noticed that the time between events seems to vary during different parts of the day (e.g., time gaps increase during nighttime, when people are likely sleeping) and possibly over weekends (when people might be on vacation). These patterns might be useful for modeling, though I'm not entirely sure how to incorporate them effectively.
To provide more context, I've attached two plots:

The first plot shows the time differences between consecutive events:


The second plot shows how the timestamps progress over time:



My main goal is to build a model that can predict the timestamp of the next event, given the most recent timestamp (or perhaps a few previous ones).
Here's where I could use your guidance:

What are the traditional statistical approaches (e.g., time series models) for this kind of time-to-next-event prediction? Is there a preferred way to handle time-varying patterns, such as daily or weekly seasonality?
Are there machine learning approaches that could work well here? I was wondering if training a neural network (e.g., RNN, LSTM) could be beneficial, especially if I feed it the latest timestamp and recent time differences.
Which techniques would you suggest for detecting patterns in the time differences and improving prediction accuracy, whether classic methods or machine learning?

I'm sure similar problems have been tackled before, but I'm not sure where to start. I'd really appreciate any advice, including suggestions on specific models, architectures, or even existing experiments I can look at.

Can you be more specific about your data? What are these events?

The events are client requests submitted to a website. Each timestamp represents when a request was made, and I’m trying to predict when the next one will occur based on the timing of previous requests. @mkt

Please edit this into the question.

"Standard" time series methods (that is, stuff you will find by googling "time series") usually work with regular series, i.e., ones where time is bucketized, and you see a numerical observation for each bucket, which could be minutes, hours, days etc.
Your case is different. I would rather start searching for "waiting times" and similar terms.
I personally think I know a little about forecasting, but waiting times forecasting is not really my core specialty. So take my suggestions with a grain of salt.
First off, associate with each time stamp the subsequent waiting time until the next event. This is what you want to forecast. You now have an irregular time series.
Next, split your data into a training, test and validation sample by time, e.g., the first 60%, middle 20% and last 20%, as standard in forecasting.
Now assess possible multiple-seasonalities, by plotting waiting times against time of day, separately for each day of week, see here. Put seven loess smoothers through your data, one for each day, to see actual patterns. Depending on the length of your data, you might also take a look at intra-yearly seasonality, by collecting data points per month or quarter and smoothing those.
For modeling, I would use trigonometric transforms of the time of day as predictors, plus six or seven dummies for the day of week, possibly more trigonometric transforms of the time of year.
You can absolutely include lags, but this is of course a little more tricky with irregular time series. One possibility would be to use the previous $k$ waiting times. It might be possible to instead use, say, the average waiting time over all events in the previous $k$ hours... but in extreme cases, you might not have a single event in this time period, so it's a little unclear what value of the predictor to use in this case.
You can then feed these predictors into an exponential regression, since the exponential distribution is an intuitive choice for waiting times. If you find you need more flexibility (you do seem to have enough data to fit a number of parameters), you can use a GAMLSS with a gamma distribution, which generalizes the exponential. Such parametric approaches have the advantage of immediately giving you predictive densities and prediction intervals.
Of course, you can also use methods based on neural nets or boosting, with the same predictors. In this case, you can train multiple models using pinball losses to get quantile forecasts if you need those.


Here's where I could use your guidance:

What are the traditional statistical approaches ...
Are there machine learning approaches ...
Which techniques would you suggest for detecting patterns ...


Use your eyes and common sense.

Is there a reason to believe that there is a correlation between time stamps? I would suspect that such requests come in just independent and randomly like a Poisson process with a varying rate.
Then you could just model the rate of requests at a given time of the day. After that, to investigate whether there is an influence of earlier requests, you can compare differences between modeled waiting times (based on the estimated frequencies) and observed waiting times.

It would be useful to explore your data with several additional plots. Aside from the current one for waiting times being difficult to read (the bars overlap), it also doesn't provide the information as function of time.
You could first try to get a grasp of the main pattern in the periodic variation in the waiting times. This doesn't require elaborate analytical methods. Just looking as a start, instead of attacking it with blackbox automatic functions, is most helpful. For example, is it the time of the week, then just plot the data as a function of time while adding grid lines for weeks, and you'll see.
Domain information is also useful. Describe the background and the underlying process.



@Mycroft_47 Also, the goal of the prediction is not very clear. Why do you want to know the expected waiting time until the next timestamp? It sounds like a limited type of statistic/prediction. What do you need it for? There are many other variables that could be considered, for example the expected number of timestamps in the next 24/48/168 hours (which might help in planning resources for the short time periods).
